# .exe created using install4j throwing SQLException

Tags: java, install4j

Converting .jar to .exe using install4j. 
.jar is working absolutely fine but when I converted to .exe using install4j it's throwing an error of SQLException. Please help

Comment: What is the message of the exception?

Comment: why would you want to create an exe? what is the exact stacktrace? ... ?

Comment: do you have a .properties file with parameters? can you include a sample of the error?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.

Please provide us with as much information as possible. At this moment we need to know the error message with further information about the SQLExeption and it would be very helpful to see any properties or configs you used

Comment: I have written sql connection statements in try block and it's catching SQLException

Comment: I have found the cause of error. It is producing this error because I have installed the .exe in C drive Windows 10 and due to database(SQLITE) in c drive it is unable to insert record into the database and produce error below  org.sqlite.SQLEXCEPTION:[SQLITE_CANTOPEN] Unable to open the database file (unable to open database file).
               How can I make installer using install4j so that the files it contain should be editable in C drive.